# How can I stop this Spark flatmap, which returns massive results, failing on writing?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, flatmap

I'm using a flatmap function to split absolutely huge XML files into (tens of thousands) of smaller XML String fragments which I want to write out to Parquet. This has a high rate of stage failure; exactly where is a bit cryptic, but it seems to be somewhere when the DataFrameWriter is writing that I lose an executor, probably because I'm exceeding some storage boundary.

To give a flavour, here's the class that's used in the flatMap, with some pseudo-code. Note that the class returns an Iterable - which I had hoped would allow Spark to stream the results from the flatMap, rather than (I suspect) holding it all in memory before writing it:

```
class XmlIterator(filepath: String, split_element: String) extends Iterable[String] {

   // open an XMLEventReader on a FileInputStream on the filepath
   // Implement an Iterable that returns a chunk of the XML file at a time

   def iterator = new Iterator[String] {
      def hasNext = { 
        // advance in the input stream and return true if there's something to return
      }
      def next = {
        // return the current chunk as a String
      }
  }
}
```

And here is how I use it:

```
var dat = [a one-column DataFrame containing a bunch of paths to giga-files]

dat.repartition(1375) // repartition to the number of rows, as I want the DataFrameWriter 
                      // to write out as soon as each file is processed
  .flatMap(rec => new XmlIterator(rec, "bibrecord"))
  .write
  .parquet("some_path")
```

This works beautifully for a few files in parallel but for larger batches I suffer stage failure. One part of the stack trace suggests to me that Spark is in fact holding the entire results of each flatMap as an array before writing out:

```
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
```

To be honest, I thought that by implementing the flatMap as an Iterable Spark would be able to pull the results out one-by-one and avoid buffering the entire results in memory, but I'm a bit baffled.

Can anyone suggest an alternative, more memory-efficient strategy for saving out the results of the flatMap?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I've managed to solve this myself by adding an intermediate stage that persists the flatMap output to disk. This lets me repartition the output of the flatmap before passing to a DataFrameWriter. Works seamlessly.

```
dat.repartition(1375)
  .flatMap(rec => new XmlIterator(rec, "bibrecord"))
  .persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
  .repartition(5000)
  .write
  .parquet("some_path")
```

I suspect that trying to pass the flatMap output directly to a DataFrameWriter was overwhelming some internal buffer - the output from each flatMap could be as much as 5GB, and I assume Spark was needing to hold this in memory.

If anyone has comments or pointers to the internal workings of the DataFrameWriter that would be super interesting.